# Need to Combine column values from multiple rows into single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this query i am getting similar rows with multiple values. Need to combine values within single row. I tried using Stuff but i am unable to do so. Need to organise data with only SQL functions and no Pl/SQL code if possible.

```
STUFF((SELECT '| ' + udn1.DisplayName 
          FROM vUserDisplayName udn1
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [USERS]
```

```
SELECT  gdn.DisplayName,
            ,ISNULL(udn.DisplayName, N'No user assigned') AS [User]
    
        FROM tbGroup g 
            INNER JOIN vGroupDisplayName gdn
                ON g.GroupId = gdn.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUserGroup ug
                ON g.GroupId = ug.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUser u
                ON ug.UserId = u.UserId 
            LEFT JOIN vUserDisplayName udn
                ON u.UserId = udn.UserId 
        WHERE
            (u.[Enabled] = 1 OR u.UserId IS NULL)
            AND
            g.IsPersonal = 0
            AND
            g.SystemGroup = 0
```

Output :

```
DisplayName                User
a                     abc@gmail.com
a                     def@gmail.com
a                     ghi@gmail.com
b                     ghi@gmail.com
b                     jkl@gmail.com
b                     mno@gmail.com
c                     pqr@gmail.com
c                     stu@gmail.com
c                     vwx@gmail.com
```

Expected Output :

```
DisplayName                User
a                     abc@gmail.com|def@gmail.com|ghi@gmail.com                  
b                     ghi@gmail.com|jkl@gmail.com|mno@gmail.com              
c                     pqr@gmail.com|stu@gmail.com|vwx@gmail.com
```

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql or sql-server?

Comment: This is sql server syntax, not mysql.

Comment: Yes it is sql-server syntax. sorry by mistake i have added mysql in tags.

Comment: sql server 2017 or higher?

Comment: Sorry, it is SQlServer V16

Comment: Stop splattering [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) in your code.

Comment: yes @marc_s. It is SQL Server 2016

Comment: done with it@SMor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016:

Using common table expression:

```
With cte as
(
        SELECT  gdn.DisplayName,
            ISNULL(udn.DisplayName, N'No user assigned') AS [User]
    
        FROM tbGroup g 
            INNER JOIN vGroupDisplayName gdn
                ON g.GroupId = gdn.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUserGroup ug
                ON g.GroupId = ug.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUser u
                ON ug.UserId = u.UserId 
            LEFT JOIN vUserDisplayName udn WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON u.UserId = udn.UserId 
        WHERE
            (u.[Enabled] = 1 OR u.UserId IS NULL)
            AND
            g.IsPersonal = 0
            AND
            g.SystemGroup = 0
)
       SElecT displayname, STUFF((SELECT  '|' + ([user])
            FROM cte tt where  tt.displayname=t.displayname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        from cte t group by displayname
```

Using subquery:

```
   SElecT displayname, STUFF((SELECT  '|' + ([user])
        FROM ( SELECT  gdn.DisplayName,
        ISNULL(udn.DisplayName, N'No user assigned') AS [User]

    FROM tbGroup g 
        INNER JOIN vGroupDisplayName gdn
            ON g.GroupId = gdn.GroupId
        LEFT JOIN tbUserGroup ug
            ON g.GroupId = ug.GroupId
        LEFT JOIN tbUser u
            ON ug.UserId = u.UserId 
        LEFT JOIN vUserDisplayName udn WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON u.UserId = udn.UserId 
    WHERE
        (u.[Enabled] = 1 OR u.UserId IS NULL)
        AND
        g.IsPersonal = 0
        AND
        g.SystemGroup = 0) tt where  tt.displayname=t.displayname
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
    from ( SELECT  gdn.DisplayName,
        ISNULL(udn.DisplayName, N'No user assigned') AS [User]

    FROM tbGroup g 
        INNER JOIN vGroupDisplayName gdn
            ON g.GroupId = gdn.GroupId
        LEFT JOIN tbUserGroup ug
            ON g.GroupId = ug.GroupId
        LEFT JOIN tbUser u
            ON ug.UserId = u.UserId 
        LEFT JOIN vUserDisplayName udn WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON u.UserId = udn.UserId 
    WHERE
        (u.[Enabled] = 1 OR u.UserId IS NULL)
        AND
        g.IsPersonal = 0
        AND
        g.SystemGroup = 0) t group by displayname
```

You can use `string_agg()` for sql server 2017 and onward versions.

```
  SELECT  gdn.DisplayName,
            string_agg(ISNULL(udn.DisplayName, N'No user assigned'),'|') AS [User]
    
        FROM tbGroup g 
            INNER JOIN vGroupDisplayName gdn
                ON g.GroupId = gdn.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUserGroup ug
                ON g.GroupId = ug.GroupId
            LEFT JOIN tbUser u
                ON ug.UserId = u.UserId 
            LEFT JOIN vUserDisplayName udn WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON u.UserId = udn.UserId 
        WHERE
            (u.[Enabled] = 1 OR u.UserId IS NULL)
            AND
            g.IsPersonal = 0
            AND
            g.SystemGroup = 0
        group by gdn.DisplayName
```

Fiddle example:

```
 create table testtable( DisplayName varchar(10), [User] varchar(50));
 insert into testtable values('a',                     'abc@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('a',                     'def@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('a',                     'ghi@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('b',                     'ghi@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('b',                     'jkl@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('b',                     'mno@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('c',                    'pqr@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('c',                    'stu@gmail.com');
 insert into testtable values('c',                     'vwx@gmail.com');
```

Query:

```
 select displayname,string_agg([User],'|') as [User] from testtable
 group by displayname
 GO
```

Output:

| displayname | User |
| --- | --- |
| a | abc@gmail.com | ghi@gmail.com |
| b | ghi@gmail.com | mno@gmail.com |
| c | pqr@gmail.com | vwx@gmail.com |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7943887ee0b0d4b036b0205dcaf140e0)*

Comment: Its really strange. STRING_AGG is showing as in-built function as recommendation but when i use that, it says its not in-built function and throwing error as :
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: Please execute select @@VERSION and share the result.

Comment: My Bad : i am new to all this. Its V16
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64)   Mar 19 2021 19:41:38   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: SQL server 2016 doesn't support string_agg()

Comment: Yea. i just read on Google. Do we have other options here?

Comment: Stuff() with XML Path For() as you mentioned in your question. I have just revised my answer

Comment: Sorry to disturb again But is it possible if we can use it without "With" clause. The issue is, its working fine at backend. But there is an sql interpreter box in frontend for reporting which i guess is not supporting temporary tables. I don't know the exact issue here but it says the query is invalid for reporting.

Comment: Try `;with` and please let me know whether it worked.

Comment: I have revised my answer. Replaced CTE with subquery. The query seems clumsy but it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error. All the queries provided by you are fine. Don't able to understand what is the issue here and why it is not accepting it.

Comment: Which reporting tool you are using? What's the error? An alternative can be to write an stored procedure then call the stored procedure from reporting tool.

Comment: It simply says "SQL is not valid for reporting". Its built-in with an web application where reports can be availble to users. I am not authorized to write its name on public platforms. Also, i need to merge this data with the data from another query. Thats why, stored procedures thing will be very dificult for me.

Comment: I am extremely sorry then. Without proper knowledge of your platform I can not suggest anything. And I respect your ethical point of view for not disclosing the name.

Comment: @Sunny I have also tried to answer another question of you. Please check and let me now your observations.